# Delphi IDE locks because of a hidden modal window

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2010

Has someone else experienced something like this with Delphi and if so is there a known workaround!

I'm using the Delphi 2010 Rad Studio on Windows 7 64 bit.

A few times when editing the IDE hangs and I can't do any action either by keyboard or mouse. But there is a error-beep sound from windows like there is a modal window open somewhere, but hidden behind the ide it self.

Only by ending the ide via Task manager can I make this hidden modal window visible.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem with older versions of Delphi like D6.

My solution is use another tool like [WinExp](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/winexp.html) –Windows Explorer– or WinResQ to explore the existing active windows on system and reactivate it (BringToTop).

With this solution I get the Delphi IDE on Top and appears the window that cause the lock.   This is the only option I have worked for me.

Regards.

[image: WinExplorar tool -There are similar on the web-]

Comment: Thanks to jachguate for add the link.   Extended information abour this tools; Windows Explorer (by NirSoft,  http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/winexp.html), Spy & Capture (by KrichMar Kobi, -http://kobik.net/-).

Answer (score 4):

I see this often with various other dialogs as well.

Pressing "Alt-Tab" and reselecting Delphi you will cause the dialog to appear in the front again.

Note: This happens with other versions of Delphi as well.

Comment: I have tried Alt+Tab, but that does not help, maybe Background compile setting has something to do with this

Answer (score 0):

Alt+Tab works, but you have to select another application, then Alt+Tab to return to Delphi, and then the dialog will show in front.